# Google Script to copy and paste values from one column to another upon edits

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I want to copy and paste cells only from one column to another and retain only the value (and not the formulas).

[See this spreadsheet.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zebBcefZpR_wHFn3tjxYBGhqTZAtSEOhI03TCpCiUOg/edit?usp=sharing)

Basically, whatever is in column D, I want to copy to column C (highlighted) upon changes in column C. On the actual sheet (this is a static copy), column D is a dynamic cell and it changes everyday. Therefore whenever column D changes, I want to automatically copy the cell values to column C. I think this can be done with Google Scripts only.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried in order to accomplish your task? @Someone

Comment: I've originally tried to use regular Google Sheets formulas, of which I'm decent at, but since the items in column D are technically formulas (even though you need to force an update), it views it at a circular dependency. I've also looked around here and tried copying what has already been done, but those are mostly relevant to copying to a new sheet, not a new column.

Answer (score 0):

A solution to your problem is to make use of Apps Script's triggers.

Since the `onEdit()` Apps Script trigger **does not** work if the changes are made by a formula, **only** by user interaction, you can make use of **time-driven triggers**.

So, for example, you can set up a trigger which will fire every day at a specific time:

#### Snippet

```
function createTimeDrivenTriggers() {
   ScriptApp.newTrigger('copyColumn')
       .timeBased()
       .everyDays(1)
       .atHour(9)
       .create();
}

function copyColumn() { 
   //function for copying the columns
}
```

#### Explanation

The snippet above creates a time based trigger which will fire every day at *approximately* 9:00. The trigger is attached to the function `copyColumn` which is used for copying the column and pasting it where needed.

For copying the column you might want to make use of some of the below methods in Apps Script:

- [`getRange()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns) - used to get the range from where the values are taken / where the values will be pasted;
- [`getValues()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues) - used to retrieve the values;
- [`setValues()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues) - used to paste the values;

#### Note

Please take into account that you might need to make use of other methods as well and adapt them to your particular case. Same goes with the time-driven trigger - you might need to customize it to your liking and add / remove some of the options that have been set in this example here.

#### Reference

- [Installable Triggers Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable);
- [ClockTriggerBuilder Class Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder);
- [Sheet Class Apps Script - getRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns);
- [Range Class Apps Script - getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues);
- [Range Class Apps Script - setValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues).